# How to setup nginx with different domains on one port and in one server block

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1 domain2 domain3

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        proxy_connect_timeout   120;
        proxy_send_timeout      120;
        proxy_read_timeout      180;
    }
}

server {
     listen domainX:80;
     server_name domainX www.domainX

     location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

            proxy_connect_timeout   120;
            proxy_send_timeout      120;
            proxy_read_timeout      180;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|bmp|swf|css|js)$ {
            root domainXStaticRoot
    }

    # other options for domainX only
}
```

for domains from first server block nginx returns only root page:

```
http://domain1 -> returns root page for domain1
http://domain1/style.css -> nginx trying return according location from server block two eg domainXStaticRoot/style.css
```

If modify
    listen 80;
to
    listen domain1:80;
then for domain1 all works fine, but i not found how write multiple domains in listen directive.

where my mistake?